# django html inicial text in form

Tags: html, django, django-forms

I have a django form with a `forms.Textarea` that contains html. If I want the user to see the text he has written whenever he wants to edit the html, how can I fill the `<textarea>` without django showing all the `<p>`s and the `<br`s?

I am using [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/) in the fron, just a javascript library for rich text editing. How can I fill this field with django initial values?

Comment: you can try using [django's safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe) filter

Answer (score 0):

Django's `|safe` filter doesn't work in this case since you can'a place it anywhere (the form renders the html automatically). What solved it is the `{% autoescape off %} {% endautoescape %}` tags.